# Connection string to a docker container in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, docker

I need help in writing a connection string to connect to a SQL Server database which is running in a docker container.

It's a .NET app that needs to be connected, but initially I want to test the connections with the database I have on SQL Server on docker.

IDE being used is Riders, OS is Mac OS.

Comment: do you have any idea about what connection string will contain ??

Comment: Yes, little bit as I am beginner. It needs server name, user name, pass word, port number and we can also mention a specific db name.

Answer (score 6):

If your .NET app is running into docker in the same solution, you have to use the name of sql server container.

docker-compose.yml

```
sqlserver:
    image: 'microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest'
    container_name: sqlserver
    volumes:
      - 'mssql-server-linux-data:/var/opt/mssql/data'
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA='Y'
      - SA_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
    ports:
      - '1433:1433'
```

Your connection string will be :

```
"ConnectionString": "Server=sqlserver;Database=xxxx;User Id=xx;Password=xxx;"
```

Otherwise, use in Server parameter the IP address for the computer hosting the container.

Comment: Hello @Raul Martin Ramos. Thank you for your  help. However am running my app on my Mac and SQL server is on docker. In the visual studio(changed me IDE from previous) should I add the docker file above and connect it. Am a bit confused about all this process.

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, If  docker is running in you mac machine, you should access by localhost. Example :  var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=xxxxx;User Id=xx;Password=xxxx;");